# Mysqlslap benchmark in freebsd

Tags: mysql, dynamic-programming, freebsd

I am new in Unix world and I would like someone to help me ASAB.

How to use a benchmark to measure the storage performance in Freebsd? It is more than this but I do not even know how to start. I install Mysql because it has its own benchmark mysqlslp, then form this I will use PROFILE to trace the query and what the storage performance is, such as average speed and other, but how can I retrieve the result output ? Then make a framework for this.

The file system is ZFS, and the network protocol is NFS. the OS is Freebsd.

Comment: Please post the program you wrote and the error messages that you have received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance of MySQL depends on a number of factors, not just storage.  So, it wouldn't exactly be a storage benchmark.

If you just want a basic synthetic filesystem benchmark, just use bonnie++. You can install it from a package.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. the Idea is that I would like to measure  the storage performance through stress. I used mysqlslap to mimic the stress from 100 of clients. then I should see what the stooge performance , the average speed and other. I found tool called proofing that will trace the query from the virtual machine to the server storage. I still can't do it.